# Create a new column based on row in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

So the basic premise is that I want to combine 6 columns that represent a person's "concern" over a virus.  Each of the columns is either a 1 for yes or 0 for no.  So they would have only one 1 per set of columns.

1. Columns 1, 2 and 3 should be 0 for concern
2. Column 4 should be 1
3. Column 5 should be 2
4. Column 6 should be 3

Example:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Result:

| Column7 |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

I have tried the code below but it returns a column of 0.

```
#setup the logic for getting the responses of 1 in each of the columns
conditions = [(survey['Column1'] == '1') | (survey['Column2'] == '1') | (survey['Column3'] == '1'),
             (survey['Column4'] == '1'), (survey['Column5']) == '1', (survey['Column6']) == '1']

#setup the values that are going to be placed into the column for the conditions
values = [0, 1, 2, 3]

#creating the column
df['Column7'] = np.select(conditions, values, default = 0)
```

This dataset is going to be used to make some predictive models, but I'm also wondering if I'm making this too hard and should just leave the columns as 0/1 instead of assigning these values to the columns results.

Comment: why do you assign columns 1,2,3 to be zero?

Comment: Why do you assign columns 4,5,6 to 1,2,3?

Comment: The idea is that column 1, 2 and 3 represent refused, don't know, and none.  They are all equal in my eyes and are assigned 0.  Column 4 is not very concerned and assigned a 1, column 5 is somewhat and assigned a 2 and column 6 is very concerned and gets a 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a weight value for each column and then sum up the weight per row:

```py
weight = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
df["Column7"] = df.loc[:, "Column1":"Column6"].mul(weight).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you very much, that seems to have worked.  Does it make sense to change the columns to the 0-3 or just leave each column with its 0 or 1 for modeling?